# PHP, MySql Vote/rate system

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

First of all sorry for the wall of text :S

Ok, here is my problem.
I'm building a web app with codeigniter and mysql. Main thing will be that ppl will leave posts, other will rate it, leave comments etc. Now, when i think of it, doing update to database on every single vote up/down is pretty supid, right? I mean what if 500+ ppl are on site and they are reading + voting posts... that would crash my site like instant (or would it, i rly don't know), since I would have so many queries for every single vote up/down. 
  So, my question is, how to solve this? Some global associative array to store id of the post as a key and +1/-1 as a value? And than some sort of "timed sql query" (if there is such thing?) to update votes lets say every 2 or 5 mins or so, and just "refresh" vote counter with ajax until I update database? Basically I'm thinking best performance in case my site goes boom :P. Can it be done with page caching or idk?

2nd issue is that u won't have to register to leave post/vote other post (i have figured everything about it, u can't post spam/garbage), but the main issue for me is how to limit one vote per post per user, since they are guests? What i googled out (was very vague) is presistent cookies, so is it the way to go or no?

I'm not asking for sample codes, just for some guide lines what to research, how to approach the problem, where to look, to get a solution. If u have some suggestions on how to solve this, it would be VERY appreciated.

Thank you, and again, sorry for the wall of text.

Answer (score 0):

1) You'd store the votes in a database and update via ajax as required, have ajax auto update the count for the end user every 30 seconds. Your biggest issue is the number of items stored in the table (10,000's records will mean you'll need to implement indexing etc).

You're only going to need to have 1 php function, based on the $action, have it case for a + or a -. The SQL queries would be rather simple actually.

Whilst you'll run into individual bottlenecks around certain elements in the application, if you keep proper records etc you can always nut it out. Just watch out for the "Update" that tells people what the vote is currently at + the auto update, realistically an ajax refresh of 1 element is preferable to loading the entire page again just to show the updated count so it's a double edged sword really.

2) Don't. Trust. The. User. Cookies are bad. Use them as a way to find out if someone is tampering with data and then prevent access if they're suspected. Store user data in the database again however given there isn't a login or user credentials, you'll only be able to store IP Address and User-Agent as usefull details - Again these can be manipulated client side, so can you really trust them?

Gl, hf.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 0.02$...

For the voting system, you don't have much of a choice but to update a table in a database right away. You could enclose the updates in transactions and implement some kind of a queue, but for 500 people I doubt this will be necessary, since MySQL can handle a few thousands of queries per second (depening on the queries of course), and other databases can go even further. A good rule of thumb is to optimize when necessary, not prematurely. So my advice on this is to just go on and try.

Second, about the registered users issue - imagine you set a voting system with persistent cookies. Which means once you set a cookie, it stays there unless the user deletes it.

Now imagine a malicious user who wants to upvote something very badly - he will try to come up with a script that visits the URL, upvotes, deletes his cookies, and start from the beginning until he makes, like, 10000 votes. Not good.

You could restrict him by an IP address, but using a proxy/Tor is so trivial that it just doesn't deserve mentioning. And this is why many systems out there (including SO) require to be registered before voting/commenting/doing any action that could become very nasty spam.

Lastly, if you've never before built such a system, but you want to learn how to do the job properly, the first thing you have to do is **research**. Google everything you can think of related to the problem. Search here in Stack Overflow. Bring the whole system down to very tiny pieces and ask yourself "How could I do that?" until you start picturing it in your head in terms of code. A good research will save you a lot of headaches later, and will help you develop your programming skills.

Cheers!